# how to Post data in certain format in android

Tags: android

Suppose user enter the 10 digit number in edit text for example 1234567890 .

```
public class main extends Activity {

    EditText number;
    @override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        number=(EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.munber);

        String pno=number.getText().toString();
```

Now I have to send (http Post) this number in (123)456-7890 format to server side on submit click. How can I achieve this?

If you have an example then share with me.

Comment: Would it make sense to let the server do all the heavy lifting? If it could accept data in any format and then parse, that would simplify your app.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to reformat the string is

```
String pno=number.getText().toString();
String hpno = "(" + pno.substring(0,3) + ")" + pno.substring(3,6) + "-"+pno.substring(6, pno.length());
```

and then you can post that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I know of is using the HttpClient library:

```
public static String postRequest(String uri) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Error: Could not connect to host");
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
        post.setURI(new URI(uri);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        in = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That will perform a post and return the response to your client.  Works well for me for a simple REST CRUD application.

ref: [here](http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/)